# "People are opting to pay their bills" — grammatical or not?

Tags: word-usage, tense, phrasal-verbs

Can someone please tell me if the following usage of *opt in* is appropriate:

> These days large number of People are **opting to pay** their bills online.

Comment: They're not "opting in", they are simply "opting", which is to say "choosing."

Answer (score 4):

"Opting to pay" in this context is unexceptionable, but there is no reason whatsoever to capitalize *people* unless you are writing an Amendment to the US Constitution, and you are missing an article before *a large number*. Also, you can use Simple Present rather than Present Continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the use of *opting to* is appropriate for this sentence and sounds natural. To echo what ЯegDwight said, 'people' isn't a proper noun and therefore shouldn't be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The present continuous is often used to contrast the past with the present in this way. It is a very vivid way of presenting something this is becoming increasingly common, as in your example.

However your sentence should read:

> These days **a** large number of people (no caps) are opting to pay their bills online.